# How to set an array size to a variable which might change later into the code?

Tags: array

I'm trying to initialize an array globally which could be of different sizes according to future code in Arduino. 
`int n=0;
int val[n];`
This says that the array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token. This also says that the val variable wasn't declared.

I have browsed other forms and have been told to use dynamic storage usage which I don't know how to use.

I'm trying to store different weight values respective to time in a variable. I first tried to store the weight in one variable but couldn't find the total weight etc.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code in "text format". There is a "button" on the Edit window tool bar that looks like this `{}`. Highlight all of your code then click it.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. The array of variable size is not the real goal, and is most likely a bad idea in the first place. What is your real purpose? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: why not use `int val[10]` or `int val[50]`?

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, dynamically allocated memory is often problematic on a memory-starved device like an Arduino. As you create and release memory, the "heap" (a pool of memory to be used for that purpose) gets broken up into "islands" of free memory with still-used blocks of memory peppered throughout.

In fairly short order you wind up with your available memory pretty much unusable, your app runs out of available memory, and your app crashes.

This is known as "heap fragmentation". When you only have a couple of K of RAM to work with, it quickly becomes fatal.

If you can be sure that you allocate a dynamic buffer in a function call sequence, don't do any other dynamic memory allocation, and then free it before returning, you can probably get away with it without fragmentation, but you really have to be careful.

If you instead dynamically allocate a block of memory very early in your app's life and then keep it for the entire run that can be okay too. That block takes a chunk of your heap and just stays there.

A third alternative is to allocate a statically sized array at compile time that's big enough for your largest use, and treat that as a buffer. You can save contents there as needed, then when you're done with those contents, use the buffer for something else.

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino platform uses a C / C++ compiler.  In C++ one can use features such as [Vectors](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vector-in-cpp-stl/) to create what appear as arrays of varying sizes.  However, it is likely memory is wasted when trying to abstract the memory usage from the application in this way.  In an embedded environment, memory is likely at a premium.  Consequently, it is almost always better to handle array sizes in embedded situations by allocating the expected amount manually at the beginning of the program.

Tip: If the size of the array depends on the situation the application is used in and there are advantages of smaller verses larger arrays depending on the application, try using [Conditional Compiling](http://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap3/subsection2.1.3.4.html) to create different versions of the application.

Answer (score 0):

In general arrays declared like

```
int array[n];
```

needs a constant size `n`, so that the correct memory size can be allocated at the time of declaration. Otherwise the compiler doesn't know what to do with that variable. You cannot change the size of an array, especially not by simply assigning values to non-existent elements. To create a new array with a size unknown at compile time, you would need to use dynamic allocation:

```
int *array = new int[n];
```

The variable `array` is actually not the array itself, but a pointer to an integer array. The compiler will create the pointer variable, which will only hold an address, where the new dynamically created array is stored. With the `new` keyword we are allocating a new memory space. With `int[n]` we are telling the program to allocate space for `n` integers. You can create arrays with sizes unknown at compile time, but you cannot change the size of an array. You would need to create a new one to change size. Dynamically allocated storage, that is not needed anymore should be freed. (You can google more about this)

**BUT: On an Arduino you should not use dynamic allocation.** If you use the dynamic allocation too much (over and over again) in a program, you will get memory fragmentation. As you allocate and free memory of different sizes, you will get many small memory spaces, which are too small to hold your new arrays. So this memory is now useless and Arduinos only have very little RAM to use for dynamic memory. When your RAM is full, your program will crash. Real computers - in contrast - have loads of memory, so that is not a problem there.

It is better to allocate your memory statically, with enough space to handle your biggest expected amount of data. So you should really think about, if you really need dynamic allocation. I would say no.

---

There are also other problems with your code.

- You use the following for loop:

  ```
  for(n = 0; isFinished = true; n++)
  ```

  A single `=` marks an assignment. So at the start of every for loop iteration you are assigning `true` to `isFinished`. And every assignment will evaluate as true. So you have an infinite loop there. If you want to check for equality, you need to use `==` (double equal sign). Also in that for loop `isFinished` newer changes. You initialize it with `false`, so the loop will not run once. If you instead check for it to be `false` the loop  will be infinite, since there is no possibility, that this variable changes inside the loop. Instead use `n` for the loop condition and run the loop as many times as you have elements in your array.
- Generally your logic seems not well thought through. You are already using a for loop to measure multiple values, so why don't you just directly measure as many values, as you want to measure, by using the for loop as described above. Then you don't need all the `isFinished` stuff, because you will always have all the needed values, when you exit the for loop. So you also don't need to check, if there are enough values measured. And it is not clear, what the threshold check should do.